# Median of an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, median

I am trying to find the median of an array.
I have done quite some research and if this seemed to be asked several times, no answers were satisfying.

**Creating my array works perfectly but when I call the function the array is sorted but it returns different values, from NaN to the first value of the array**

How to find the median value of the length, and then from it's index find the median value of the array?

```js
var ar1 = [];

while (true) {
  var enterValues = prompt("enter your values");
  if (enterValues != "") {
    ar1.push(enterValues);
  } else {
    break;
  }
}

function calcMedian() {
  
  var half = Math.floor(ar1.length / 2);
  ar1.sort(function(a, b) { return a - b;});

  if (ar1.length % 2) {
    return ar1[half];
  } else {
    return (ar1[half] + ar1[half] + 1) / 2.0;
  }
}

console.log(ar1);
console.log(ar1.length);
console.log(calcMedian());
console.log(ar1);
```

*(ps:to stop filling the array just enter without value.)*

Comment: The prompt is annoying. :(

Comment: Median of an array is just the middle element: `arr[Math.floor(arr.length/2)]`. Unsure what you mean by: *"How to find the median value of the length"*

Comment: the prompt is to try on several lengths, just remove it if you will and create your own array, won't change the end result nor my understanding of a correct way.

Comment: "1" + "2" makes "12"

Comment: why the dot for numbers without fraction part? javascript knows only numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var ar1 = [];

while (true) {
  var enterValues = prompt("enter your values");
  if (enterValues != "") {
    ar1.push(parseFloat(enterValues));
  } else {
    break;
  }
}

function calcMedian() {
  var half = Math.floor(ar1.length / 2);
  
  ar1.sort(function(a, b) { return a - b;});
  
  if (ar1.length % 2) {
    return ar1[half];
  } else {
    return (ar1[half-1] + ar1[half]) / 2.0;
  }
}

console.log(ar1);
console.log(ar1.length);
console.log(calcMedian());
console.log(ar1);
```

`Math.floor(ar1.length)` will return (for example) `4` is the length is `8`. However, if you do `ar1[4]` it will actually return the ***fifth*** item in the array as the array index starts at zero. So `ar1[4-1]` will return the fourth item, add it to `ar1[4]` which is the fifth item and divide it by two to find the median. If the length is odd, it will return (for example) `3` if the length is `7`. It then retrieves `arr[3]` which is the fourth item which is the median.

Comment: please add what you changed and why.

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 problems in your code:

1. You calculate `half` before you fill the array so it will always be 0.
2. You save the numbers as string so when you add them you don;t get the right results.

Working :

```js
var ar1 = [];


while (true) {
  var enterValues = prompt("enter your values");
  if (enterValues != "") {
    ar1.push(+enterValues);
  } else {
    break;
  }
}

function calcMedian() {
  var half = Math.floor(ar1.length / 2);
  ar1.sort(function(a, b) { return a - b;});

  if (ar1.length % 2) {
    return ar1[half];
  } else {
    return (ar1[half] + ar1[half] + 1) / 2.0;
  }
}

console.log(ar1);
console.log(ar1.length);
console.log(calcMedian());
console.log(ar1);
```

Comment: It should also be `return (ar1[half] + ar1[half+1]) / 2.0;`

Comment: actually after reviewing the code again it should be        
    
    `return (ar1[half-1] + ar1[half]) / 2.0;`

Thanks for the position of the variable though , I was totally not paying attention to that!

Answer (score 0):

```
let values = [2, 56, 3, 41, 0, 4, 100, 23];

values.sort(function(a,b) {
 return a - b;
});


let lowMiddle = Math.floor( (values.length - 1) / 2);
let highMiddle = Math.ceil( (values.length - 1) / 2);
let median = ( values[lowMiddle] + values[highMiddle]) / 2;

console.log(median);
```